# Xubuntu 14.04 conflicting Alt+Scroll behavior

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, transparency, zooming

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd>  is in Xubuntu overloaded to have two behaviors: alter window transparency when mouse is positioned on title bar, or zoom otherwise.

When I position the mouse cursor on a window title bar and scroll down, the window gets less transparent. As expected.

If I scroll upwards, hoping to restore opacity, the view zooms in. If I zoom in to maximum magnification, the opacity-control resumes, and I can restore opacity to my windows.

I would ideally like to be able to do both, but I don't want to zoom in to restore opacity to my windows. Is that possible? If so, how?

**SOLVED:** Turns out it is the horizontal scroll on window decorator that causes the transparency change. I had foolishly turned that on and scrolled with a touchpad, inevitably scolling hotizontally on accident.

Answer (score 3):

Change the key used to grab the windows to something else.

In Xubuntu 14.04, open **Settings Manager** from application menu, or run `xfce4-settings-manager` in terminal. Then, follow the instructions below.

1. Go to **Window Manager Tweak > Accessibility**
2. In the first line, look for this option^ `Key used to grab and move windows:` with a drop-down box, then click and change from the default `Alt` to other key of choice in the list.
3. Finally, click **Close** to finish.

[image: Xfce4 Window Manager Tweak - Key to grab]

I would suggest to use `Shift` key, because this key is rarely used for two-key combination shortcuts. This will avoid any conflicting shortcuts.

Another choice is `Super` key, which is what I'm using now after feeling uncomfortable with the `Shift` key.

Consider this: If `Control` key is used for the option^ (step 2), this will cause <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Mouse click to be disabled. The shortcut is useful to open a link in background tab in Firefox and other web browsers.

**Final result**: Changing the key to `Shift` will trigger the zoom function by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Mouse scroll keys and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse scroll on Xfwm title bar will trigger transparency as usual. This was tested in Xubuntu 14.04; however, these functions are inseparable and seem to rely on the same key in newer releases.